# Qual è il senso di "filare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Ma intanto cominciarono a volare oggetti dalla finestra e fu tale la curiosità che mi liberai i timpani, come se avessi bisogno di suoni nitidi per capire. Melina però non gridava parole ma solo aaah, aaah, come se fosse ferita. Non la si vedeva, di lei non compariva nemmeno un braccio o una mano che lanciava le cose. Pentole di rame, bicchieri, bottiglie, piatti parevano volare dalla finestra per volontà propria e in strada Lidia Sarratore **filava** a testa china, la schiena curva sulla carrozzella, le figlie dietro, e Donato s’arrampicava sulla carretta tra le sue proprietà, e don Nicola tratteneva il cavallo per il morso e intanto le cose urtavano sull’asfalto, rimbalzavano, si spezzavano schizzando schegge tra le zampe nervose della bestia.

In questo passaggio,  Lidia Sarratore fa parte di una famiglia che in quel momento è in trasloco. Melina è una vicina che si è innamorata del marito di Lidia, Donato: presa dalla rabbia, grida e lancia oggetti dalla finestra.

Malgrado aver letto tutte le accezioni del [verbo "filare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/filare3/) non riesco a capire qual è il suo significato in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Probabilmente significa scappare, fuggire.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @dreadd! Your answer is probably not incorrect, but it's very poor. What we are expecting here is a more detailed and reasoned answer. Could you please expand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato corretto è il numero 4 della pagina a cui fai riferimento: si intende che Lidia procede velocemente, senza curarsi della baraonda che succede intorno a lei. Noi mi è chiaro (perché mi manca il contesto) se sia più adatto il significato 4a o 4b, probabilmente si tratta di una vita di mezzo: Lidia sta sia procedendo regolarmente che allontanandosi il prima possibile (quasi come se stesse scappando) dalla vicina che dà in escandescenze.

Il termine è comunque da intendersi utilizzato in senso colloquiale: immagino che l'etimologia sia quella suggerita dalle definizioni precedenti nella stessa pagina; originalmente il termine si riferisce al "ridurre in forma di filo" delle fibre grezze (significato 1); in questa operazione, il filo che si forma un po' alla volta scorre regolarmente tra le mani e si arrotola sul fuso (significato 2): per analogia, si dice che "fila" chi si sposta con regolarità oppure, per *understatement*, fugge via da qualcosa (significato 4).

Answer (score 0):

"Andava veloce", nel contesto, può avere accezione di fuggire tanto quanto può averlo "correva".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Luke! Your answer is probably not incorrect, but it's very poor. What we are expecting here is a more detailed and reasoned answer. Could you please expand it?

Comment: @Luke, qui ci teniamo abbastanza alla lingua italiana, come puoi immaginare. Quando rispondi, oltre a formulare le tue opinioni in modo un po' circostanziato come suggerisce Charo, potresti fare caso alle maiuscole, alla punteggiatura e all'ortografia (*“accezzione” > “accezione”)? Un italiano carente dà poca credibilità alle opinioni che esprime.